# what devices are required to setup wireless internet with dsl?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, dsl, dsl-modem

i'm new in these things. what devices are required to setup wireless internet fully. I mean from device that search for signal to `DSL` router. I've seen people install some kind of device on their roof to catch wireless signal. what's that device called and how to access that device  form my computer so I can search for available signals in my area.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: oh, sorry. I'm going to edit the comment. didn't see the frequency. -_-'

Comment: What you need is a wireless antenna booster, like this one: http://amzn.com/B0054MLMLA ; and a wireless bridge (a wireless router is okay too, but needs to have a cable port for coaxial cable). Check this one: amzn.com/B005UBNGY6 If you use a range extender (or called also a bridge), you get access to a wider range of wireless networks, and you don't need any other configuration.

Comment: thanks @ErlisD. i've subscribed to one of wireless dsl service. it was working when they setup but just after few hour they left. internet speed go down to 4-5 kb. it is still down, i called their support service.. they said its holiday today and they'll come tomorrow. i don't like their service, not sure if thats because of there poor service or poor signal. there is few other ISP in my area so just wanted to check whose signal is stronger. any i idea how to check for available ISP signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is a [Wireless Broadband](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_broadband) or a [Fixed Wireless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_wireless) and also known as [Wireless mesh network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network) . Also it is called a [point-to-multipoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-multipoint_communication) network.

> **Wireless Broadband Network**
>   A term you may recognize in association with wireless broadband internet service includes wireless network. A wireless network is a single broadband internet arrangement established for your home or office.
>
> **It requires several pieces of equipment that are all one-time cost items: a wireless transceiver, such as a wireless card or antenna, and a wireless router. In addition, you will have to purchase the broadband service, which is a continual expense.**
>
> You cannot utilize your wireless broadband tools without an ongoing broadband service. Together, the wireless devices and the broadband internet service make up your wireless broadband network. When employed, the network will send data to your broadband internet connection via these wireless tools that utilize a special wireless technology (known as Wi-Fi). As a result you will be able to access the internet from anywhere inside the coverage area, as determined by the location of your wireless router.

Got that from: http://whatismyipaddress.com/wireless
Also here is a picture of this kind of networking:
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for the info @TechLife. what i actually want to know is, is it possible to check boardband signal strength just like we check for wifi signal strength in computer.

Comment: Yes it is possible but it has technical equipments just like satellite finders (if you've seen one of them). They are not easily accessible out there and they are also expensive. This is because this a fixed networking , you dont need to check for signals every time you wanna connect to the network. Once the service man has checked for the strength of signals, it is enough and there is no need to check for signals for another time in future.

Comment: there are few ISP's in my area. everyone says their service is best. they just want to make business with us. i've installed one of them yesterday. the signal strength was around -75 . i guess that's not good signal but they said it'll work fine there won't be any disturbance. but it was down whole night and still down to just few kb/ps.  more than the service they just want to make customer. but i want to check whose signal strength is stronger in my area and want subscribe from them. so just wanted to check whose signal is stronger. i've all devices from antenna to router.

Comment: they did it with same device yesterday. with help of some ip address i guess. so, just wanted to know how they did it? how can i use those devices and antenna to scan for signals. possible?

Comment: check out this really close to what you want : http://www.deliberant.com/apc-2s-14

Comment: you are welcome. but I think another workaround is to enter websites of providers and download their map of supported range and compare these maps. This can also help.